# Problemas con retrofit y picasso

Tags: android, json, retrofit

tengo un problema con mi retrofit y picasso, al momento de llamar al servidor que es un json necesito mostrar en un listview una serie de imagenes, pero al abrir la app me sale una imagen repetida pero si cierro y abro la app me carga otra pero repetida, intente verificar con un Log si todas tenian la misma ruta y si pero es direccion de carpeta, entonces estoy buscando una opcion para poder mostrarla diferentes en el list de mi actividad.

`title.setText(dir.getTitle().subSequence(0, dir.getTitle().length()));
        comment.setText( dir.getComment().subSequence(0, dir.getComment().length()));
        publishedAt.setText(dir.getPublishedAt().subSequence(0, dir.getPublishedAt().length()));
        Picasso.with(activity).load(dir.getPicture()).into(picture);`

Answer (score 0):

Al cargar tu imagen al ejecutarse el código que expones, posiblemente dentro de `getView()`, tienes que asegurar que la imagen que carga es diferente en cada petición, en este caso `dir.getPicture()`, si no cambia, probablemente esa es la causa al ver imagenes repetidas:

```
 Picasso.with(activity).load(dir.getPicture()).into(picture);
```

`dir.getPicture()`, debe contener un url diferente de acuerdo a el elemento dentro del `ListView`.